# Straightening a bend copper tubing of an air conditioner filled with refrigerant

Tags: air-conditioning, copper-tubing

I have a bent copper-tubing of an air conditioner filled with refrigerant that I want to straighten (because I need make some space for mounting a curtain rail). Now, I'm fully aware that it is not recommended to bend/straighten a copper-tubing due to risk of:

- Leak
- Cooling inefficiency

Since, I really need to mount that rail. I was hoping that someone could see the attached images of the situation, and tell/guide whether

- these bends are really severe to cause the risks
- If so, what are my options to get this tubing straighten

> Will being filled with refrigerant (higher inner pressure) would prevent potential kink?
> [image]

---

### Images description

- **Red circles:** are the bends that I want to straighten.
- **Green arrow:** shows the desired path of the tubing
- **Box**: that the tubing runs into is a large PVC wire channel to get a cleaner look.

[image]

### Image: 02

[image]

Comment: Be aware that in the US, at least, releasing the coolant into the atmosphere is illegal. You have to have the system evacuated of coolant to prevent leaks. Something about the ozone and environment and all that. If you attempt to straighten your pipe and crack it open, you're not only releasing it into the atmosphere, you're polluting the inside of your dwelling with it. I have no idea how toxic it may be to breathe it for a while as you exit the house then wait for it to clear...

Comment: You indicate that you need space for a curtain rail. If you're hanging an actual curtain from this rail, have you considered mounting the rail above the pipe-set and using the curtain to hide the pipes? If not, maybe mount the rail just below it (for whatever purposes you have in mind), then hang a second one above it with a valence curtain to hide the pipes?

Comment: As a final thought, if you _do_ manage to straighten this, you're going to end up with _extra_ pipe. Where it exits the AC unit, it goes up ~12" (my guess). You'll add that 12" to the length of the pipe, so you'll have to bend it down the wall 12" sooner. You'll then have 24" extra inches of pipe before it heads into that hole in the corner. What are you going to do with all that extra pipe? It's not like this is a hose that you can just coil up the spare somewhere...

Comment: _considered mounting the rail above the pipe-set_ In the current situation there isn't much space to mount rail above the pipes. _What are you going to do with all that extra pipe?_ I'll probably pass it through the wall out side of room.

Comment: _I'll probably pass it through the wall out side of room_ consider that you have a set of stiff copper pipes that you're working _hard_ to remove bends from (and make at least 2 _new_ 90° bends in), it might be difficult to _just_ "pass it through the wall". It's likely, IMHO, that you'll ruin the pipes in the attempt, but feel free to give this a shot. Just be fully prepared (mentally and financially) to have to do a complete replacement.

Comment: So you want to take chances and bend the pipe? Cracking the pipe and releasing the refrigerant is the least of your worries. The refrigerant is SUPER COLD., you could burn/freeze your fingers or hand really badly... Or you can loose an eye. Don't start modifying a charged system if you are not trained for it.

Answer (score 1):

First, is that electrical box secured or just hanging on its wires? if it is just hanging that needs to be addressed as well.

Then, is there any spare length in the copper pipe, assuming it is covered by the tape stuff? I think the pipes will be too short if you tried to put two 90 bends in them with a pipe bender. Also, copper pipe work hardens so the original bending will have made the pipe harder to bend a second time around.

I would consider making new pipes to meet the proper run you want then refill the system.

Comment: _is there any spare length in the copper pipe_  Yes, check second image update. There are couple of feet more on the other side of the wall.

Comment: So, get a pipe bender and see, but work hardening may still turn out to be your issue.

Comment: The way I see it, In both cases I'll need new pipes and refill the system. So, how about I take my chances in straightening the pipe ? if failed I'll still need to do the same (get new pipes and refill the system)

Comment: Up to you, do the job once for sure or maybe have to do it twice...

Comment: Actually, he'll end up with _extra_ pipe, not be too short. See my (3rd) comment on the OP.

Comment: @FreeMan that only became clear after the OP added the second image as I had to ask if there was any spare length - if you check the question and look at the original prior to the edits it becomes clear. I don’t think it makes any material difference to the isdues if re-bending pipe though... and straightening bent pipe can easily cause it to split.

Comment: fair enough. I agree (and you already had my up vote), his best course of action is to evacuate the pipes, replace with new, and refill the system. Probably _not_ a DIY project, at least not in the US, unless you're willing to invest in a fair bit of equipment.

Comment: @FreeMan thanks for the vote. according to the profile this is in Pakistan...so equipment ...

Answer (score -1):

Here is something you can try; get a "C" clamp and put it on the copper at the center of the bend and see if you can smash the copper ever so slightly to remove some of the kink. Do not squeeze the copper too much, just a little to remove some of the kink. This action will not remove the kink but it may make it less severe.  If that does not work then do as @Solar Mike wrote and redo the copper and refill the system.

Comment: I don't have a kink in tubing currently.

Comment: According to the picture you posted, a slight movement and you will have a kink. For now it may not actually be a kink but it sure is a restriction

Comment: The picture was posted as an example of a kink that the OP is explicitly trying to _avoid_, not what he currently has. (At least, that's what I understood.)