# Hammered suction pipe under slab

Tags: hvac

What happens if installer bends the larger copper pipe at two 90 degree angles within two feet by pounding the end of the pipe with a mallet to create the bend under concrete slab? I had asked them to run it overhead and I’d put a hole in the brick so it could have been welded or properly bent with 90 degree angles. Does this reduce the efficiency of the new unit? unit?  It doesn’t save money over the 10 year old 14 seer unit.  Is the suction impeded and if so, what can I do? Thank you

Comment: We can't possibly say without more detail about the pipe and the outcome. What's "large"? What do the bends look like? If you can't see it, neither can we. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

Copper pipe can be bent cold, so that's not an issue.  That is how pipe benders work.  However just beating it can deform and crush it, which may not be good.  See [another post here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/194341/straightening-a-bend-copper-tubing-of-an-air-conditioner-filled-with-refrigerant) to see how it could be damaging.

[image]

From [How to Bend Copper Pipe 3 Ways](https://www.thespruce.com/how-to-bend-copper-pipe-5081971).  I am not associated with the site, the photo comes from there.